# New MST resulting from multiple edge weights being reduced?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

We know the original graph and the original MST. Now we change k edge weights in the graph. Is there any way we can generate the new MST from the old graph in O((n + k) log n) time?

Answer (score 1):

- Start with the original MST.
- Add to the MST all edges that had their weights reduced. If the edge was already in the original MST, then just leave it there with the edge weight reduced.
- Let this new resulting graph be `G`.
- Solve MST on `G`.

MST can be solved in `O(mlogn)` time where `m` is the number of edges and `n` is the number of vertices in the graph.

Since `G` has `O(n + k)` edges, you can find the new MST in `O((n+k)logn)` time.